# Symfony 1.4: Problems with Applet on index.php (working on frontend_dev)

Tags: java, php, applet, symfony-1.4

I have an own Authentication module which is registered in the settings.yml:

```
.actions:
  login_module:           auth
  login_action:           index
```

At indexSuccess in the module auth I have an applet in which I use Java Native Access to have access to dill-libraries. The applet is signed. This is indexSucces:

```php
<?php if ($showApplet): ?>
  <applet code="attribute.class" codebase="/applet/" archive="/applet/attribute.jar, /applet/jna-4.0.0.jar" width="1" height="1">
  <param name="url" value="<?php echo $url ?>" />
</applet>
<?php else: ?>
  <?php include_partial('form', array('form' => $form)) ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

When I call my project using frontend_dev everything works fine. But when I try to call it using index.php it doesn't work (500 Internal Server Error). Is it because of safety restrictions? If so how could I get it working? Or does this problem have other reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to clear the cache ? When an issue happens on prod environment (index.php) but doesn't in dev environment (frontend_dev.php), it is often due to cache.

Just `php symfony clear cache` in command line when you are in your project root, or just erase the `cache` folder's content